# Hosting a WPF usercontrol in a Windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I have a WPF keyboard control that is hosted in a Windows form Control. It works fin on most computers, but not on all.

For some reason or another, on some computers when I open the win form with the wpf keyboard the wpf control is blank. Just get an empty square instead of the keyboard.

All of the parts of the project is in .net 3.0 and is built in C# 3.

Anybody have any ideas?

*Update*

I unfortunately don't have access to the computer my self only via a person on the other end of a phone.

I've even tried setting up a computer without .net 3.0. That gives me an error message

Tried .net 3.0 without any service pack also, but it doesn't recreate the problem.

Comment: I wasn't aware that .NET 3.0 included WPF I thought it wasn't until 3.5 that WPF and WCF was included in the Framework itself.

Comment: It is added but vs2008 dos not support showing all that is sett up in the xaml. there among Viewbox.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that you have the right version of .NET installed on the computers in which they are not working ?